# Implement BBCode lists in PHP

Tags: php, html, bbcode

I am writing a school project that allows users to post texts. To prevent HTML injection, I have decided to use BBCode.

I have written a parser in PHP, using regular expressions. My problem now is: How do I implement lists? All tags I implemented so far had a closing tag. But code like this has not:

```
[list]
  [*]item
  [*]item2
[/list]
```

Of course replacing the stars with beginning tags and ommitting the ending tags would work (since that was standard some time before I learned HTML, and browsers should support legacy constructs). But I have to produce valid HTML5, that is a requirement.

Another solution would be requiring users to use a non-standard code, but I don´t want to do that.

I tried googling it, but did not find anything useful.

Comment: http://php.net/bbcode ...

Comment: Already saw this, but not an option - third party code.